# Linux Mint: CTRL button not work for the first times after focus on any input window

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard

When I change the focus to any window where text needs to be entered (it can be a terminal, an IDE, a browser, etc.), the first few times the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> combinations don't work and just insert the letter. And later, after 1-2-3 times, they start to work properly.

Feeling as if some program intercepts this <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and only after some time releases it.

Please help fix it.

Note: This started randomly with no changes to system settings except some updates. No one touched any config with their hands, this is 100%.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-91-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0
    Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 81NE v: Lenovo IdeaPad S540-15IWL
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: No DPK serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: LENOVO v: APCN31WW date: 07/18/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 59.0 Wh (95.8%) condition: 61.6/70.1 Wh (87.9%)
    volts: 16.8 min: 15.2 model: SMP L18M4PF5 status: Charging
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i7-8565U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Comet/Whiskey Lake note: check rev: C cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB
    L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 623 high: 700 min/max: 400/4600 cores: 1: 635 2: 700
    3: 649 4: 600 5: 600 6: 600 7: 600 8: 600 bogomips: 31999
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: IMC Networks Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-4:3
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-91-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] driver: iwlwifi
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: br-1ac2f2e40bea state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: br-45804a830400 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: br-864ecca4332c state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-4: br-8da35ad00b95 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-5: br-c290156f9647 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-6: br-c49216d2fecf state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-7: br-d189c579e022 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-8: br-ee108dbaec61 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-9: CloudflareWARP state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: N/A
  IF-ID-10: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-11: veth082f7d8 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-12: veth84b7d92 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-13: veth89ff816 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-14: vethaa9063f state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-15: vethdbb3fc2 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP) type: USB
    driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-10:5
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.1
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 233.26 GiB (24.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Intel model: SSDPEKKW010T8L size: 953.87 GiB
    temp: 32.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 914.69 GiB used: 116.34 GiB (12.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
    mapped: vgmint-root
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.61 GiB used: 593.6 MiB (36.1%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 12 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C pch: 38.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 327 Uptime: 1h 54m Memory: 11.44 GiB used: 3.89 GiB (34.1%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 2376 Shell: Zsh
  v: 5.8.1 inxi: 3.3.13
```